# update or insert

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to update or insert data dependent on whether the account number is already in the existing data.
Firstly I added the new variables to those with an acocunt number already in the table using this

```
drop table #test1
select a.*, B.Delq_Sep12, b.Bal_Sep12, b.Queue_Sep12
into #test1
from  pcd1 a
left join #pcd_sep12  b on  (a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.account_number)
```

Then I add all those records whose account number is not in test1 (created above) from #pcd_sep12 into test1

```
INSERT #test1
SELECT * FROM #pcd_sep12 WHERE account_number NOT IN(SELECT account_number FROM #test1)
```

I get the error Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I realise its because theres not the same number of fields but is there a way around this?

Comment: You don't show the UPDATE in your sample, but your original statement says you are trying to INSERT or UPDATE. Are you trying to determine which to do?

Comment: you have to add  B.account_number is null to your first query to get the new records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) (aka "upsert") statement?

```
MERGE INTO pcd1 M
USING (SELECT * FROM #pcd_sep12) src ON M.account_number = src.account_number
WHEN MATCHED
-- UPDATE stuff
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
-- INSERT stuff;
```

This way you don't need a temp table or any tests: these won't be concurrency-safe under load

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the columns like this

```
INSERT INTO #test1 (column1, column2, column3)
(SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM #pcd_sep12 WHERE account_number NOT IN(SELECT account_number FROM #test1))
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am not mistaken, your #test1 table has columns from pcd1 table also. but in your second query, you are only selecting from #pcd_sep12.